# Submitting a form via a certain 'Submit' button from Javascript/JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with multiple `input type submit` buttons, and each button has a different `name` attribute that tends to POST different information.

I am trying to use SweetAlert as a form of validation.

However, the problem that I am facing is that when I put SweetAlert code (and hence needing the `e.preventDefault()` ) it posts and submits, but uses the default Submit, which does not post the right information to the backend (django python app).

```
    $('.customSubmit').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        Swal.fire({
              title: 'Are you sure?',
              text: "You're about to do XXXX.",
              type: 'warning',
              showCancelButton: true,
              confirmButtonColor: '#6b84a3',
              cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
              confirmButtonText: 'Yes!'
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.value) {
                    // This is where I want to make sure that my form submits via a particular submit button
                    $('#myForm').submit();
                }
            });
    });
```

This is the input that I want to use for submitting the form

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary customSubmit" name="customSubmit" value="Submit" />
```

This is my form

```
<form action="" method="post" name="myForm" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-with-datepicker">
<input class="text" type="checkbox" value="Name" name="form_name" />

 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submitDelete" name="submitDelete" value="Delete" />

 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary customSubmit" name="customSubmit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: I just want to clarify that confirmation and validation is different

Comment: Try adding `e.stopPropagation();`

Comment: @Francisaskquestion sorry, I just wanted a confirmation step, not validation, sorry. I tried e.stopPropagation() instead of e.preventDafult() but it submitted the form before I got to Confirm or Cancel.

Comment: Add the `stopPropagation()` not replace the `preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submitDelete" name="submitDelete" value="Delete" />
```

this u will try by using this

```
<button type="submit" name="" class=""></button>
```

and for second button also with different class

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same result as when I use <input>